# Braintree 'payment_method_nonce' returns empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, braintree, nonce

I'm fairly new to Braintree. Im integrating the DropIn UI in the Sandbox environment. The 'payment_method_nonce' is returning empty after I submit my form, which makes the transaction fail. The DropIn UI displays correctly in the specific div, and to make sure everything was working correctly I added in a place holder for the PaymentMethodNonce which was 'fake-valid-nonce', which made the transaction valid. I am stuck on why the Braintree server is not sending back a Nonce value.

I make an Ajax call to token.php to get the Client Token which enables the DropIn UI to render correctly.

Ajax call below:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "/braintree/token.php",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        braintree.setup(data, 'dropin', {container: 'dropin-container'});
    );
</script>
```

This is token.php which generates the Client Token:

```
    require ("braintree.php");

    $clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();
    echo json_encode($clientToken);
```

When I inspect the HTML, BrainTree shows a 'server-error-message' div, and it displays "There was an error processing your request. Try again." Other posts regarding this issue have mentioned that the way a HTML form can be set up and submitted can cause this issue.

Here is my Form:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="alpha-container col-12">
            <div class="content-container">
                <form id="infoForm" method="post" action="/congrats.php">

                    <div class="tab">
                        <h2>Pick a Time</h2>
                        <div>
                            <!-- Google Schedule API goes here -->
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>Distance:</h4>
                            <p></p>
                            <br>
                            <h4>Duration:</h4>
                            <p></p>
                            <h4>Estimate:</h4>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab">
                        <h2>Contact Information</h2>
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <div class="contact-block">
                                <label for="fullname"></label>
                                <input type="text" name="Data[fullname]" class="contact" placeholder="Full Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="contact-block">
                                <label for="email"></label>
                                <input type="email" name="Data[email]" class="contact" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>

                            <div class="contact-block">
                                <label for="phonenumber"></label>
                                <input type="number" name="Data[phonenumber]" class="contact" placeholder="Phone Number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab">
                        <h2>Payment Information</h2>
                        <div class="payment-form">
                            <label for="firstName"></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="Data[first_name]">

                            <label for="lastName"></label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="Data[last_name]">

                            <div id="dropin-container"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Next/Previous Buttons -->
                    <div style="overflow:auto;">
                        <div style="float:right;">
                            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Progress Bar -->
                    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                        <span class="step"></span>
                        <span class="step"></span>
                        <span class="step"></span>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form uses Javascript to hide the steps of the form and then adds a submit button then it has reached the last step. 'congrats.php' is where I'll be processing the transaction. I am including both jQuery and Braintree JS in my header.

Edit: My solution was found by editing my HTML form. The form above used javascript to add a submit button once on the last step of the form. My new form now just has a button tag with type=submit and now the 'payment_method_nonce' is being created. For whatever reason, the Braintree server was not receiving my payment information upon submit.

Comment: Where is your hidden input for the nonce?  Is that part of the drop in container?  Please inspect the HTML for your rendered page and verify the input with `name="payment_method_nonce"` exists inside your form.

Comment: @devlincarnate I did more testing and the solution was within re-structuring my HTML form. My old form structure (in post) was using JS to insert a submit button, my new form I actually add a <button> with type=submit, and this seemed to fix my issues.